# Inequality of two norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, terminology, normed-spaces

I am trying to show, if $m(E)< \infty$ and $x \in L^{\infty}(E)$, then

$$ \vert \vert x\vert \vert_{p} \leq [m(E)]^{1/p} \vert \vert x\vert \vert_{\infty}$$.

I use Hölder's inequality but did not manipulate it. This inequalitiy implies every bounded measurable function is p-th integrable i.e every open set which are open in $L^{\infty}(E)$ are open in $L^{p}(E)$, So if we consider a function from $L^{p}(E)$ to $L^{\infty}(E)$ that are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Use the obvious fact that $|x|\le \sup_{x\in E}|x|=\|x\|_{\infty}$. Then \begin{align}\|x\|_p&=\left(\int_E|x|^{p}dm(x)\right)^{1/p}\\[0.2cm]&\le \left(\int_E\sup_{x\in E}|x|^{p}dm(x)\right)^{1/p}\\[0.2cm]&=\sup_{x\in E}|x|\left(\int_Edm(x)\right)^{1/p}=m(E)^{1/p}\cdot\|x\|_{\infty}\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I understand, Can you give some light on the above thought. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are two things that you need. First that $\|x\|_{\infty}$ is finite, i.e. that $x\in L^{\infty}(E)$. And second that $m(E)$ is finite. If you have these two ingredients, then you say roughly that: " ok, I can bound $x$ by the constant function $\|x\|_{\infty}$ over the entire $E$, yes? Then, any integral of $x$ is certainly less than the integral of the constant function $\|x\|_{\infty}$ over $E$. And this exactly what you have on the RHS.

Comment: Yes, I understood, I want your comment on defining the continuous function of two spaces.

Comment: I do not understand your last question, sorry.

Comment: if we consider a function from $L^{p}(E)$ to $L^{\infty}(E)$ that are continuous

Comment: Your sentence does not make sene, I do not understand what you are asking. Functions go from $E$ to $\mathbb R$ or something, they do not go from $L^p(E)$ to $L^{\infty}(E)$.